# How to add two highlight layers using gghighlight

Tags: r, ggplot2, gghighlight

I'm trying to add 2 highlight points layers using gghighlight package.
Here is the code:

```
p$sp <- p$sp +
  gghighlight(
    pw > quantile(pw.fpi$pw, 0.95),
    fst > quantile(pw.fpi$fst, 0.95)
  ) +
  geom_point(color = "blue", size = 1) +
  gghighlight(
    pw < quantile(pw.fpi$pw, 0.05),
    fst > quantile(pw.fpi$fst, 0.95)
  ) +
  geom_point(color = "green", size = 1)
```

However, only green points layer shows in the figure, blue highlight points were covered.
Does anybody know what to do next?
Thank you

I am expecting a figure with two highlight point regions, blue points and green points exist in the figure simultaneously.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a minimal working code and a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.